# Bootstrap 4 mega menu drop down doesn't stay within container when position is fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a "mega menu" in Bootstrap 4 using the navbar. The menu uses the class `fixed-top` so that it's always on screen and has an immediate child div using the class `container` so that the contents of the menu are centered.

[image: Megamenu unopened]

I'm using the following classes to create the mega menu.

```
.megamenu-li {
    position: static;
}

.megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

The problem with this approach is when you open a mega menu, its contents go out 100% of the window width.

[image: megamenu open]

Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/bvw9mf7d/

How can I keep the megamenu within the same constraints as a div with the class of `container` ?

**What I've Tried.**

I tried to wrap the entire thing within a div with the class `container` but this doesn't affect the megamenu drop down.

I tried to change my class megamenu like this

```
.megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Which kind of works but doesn't follow the container very well. Here's the fiddle of that attempted solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/7Ln4zh9x/

I've created a third demo that shows the megamenu staying within the bootstrap container. 
https://jsfiddle.net/pgfxst5h/

The problem with this one is that it's not

- The navbar background doesn't expand the whole width
- The navbar isn't fixed

How can I achieve the effect I'm after?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: *The problem with this approach is when you open a mega menu, its contents go out 100% of the window width*. In your first fiddle the mega menu and the drop down both stay within the screen's width, could elaborate on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `.container` inside your `.megamenu`, you can constrain the width, but you'll have to add another `<div>` within it. Using the HTML/CSS below, you can make the default parent megamenu background transparent, and then use whatever background/border colors you want for the child `<div>`, which I've named `.megamenu-inner`.

[image: constrained megamenu]

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q15dxj2t/1/

```
<div class="dropdown-menu megamenu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="megamenu-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.megamenu-inner {
    background: red;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```